# terraform only name in even numbers

Tags: terraform, hashicorp

I've been using terraform for a while but by no means am I experienced with code. I've been using the below block to generate descriptions for my hosts.

```
resource "vra_deployment" "test_instance" {
  count             = var.instance_count
  catalog_item_name = var.catalog_item_name
  description = "${var.hostname_prefix}${format("%02d", count.index+2)}-${replace(lower(var.region), "-","")}"
```

This will give me a host with a description like host02-region. At the moment I've only used this with the count variable set to 1.

I'd like to make it so that if I set the count variable to 2, it will build 2 hosts with the description only in even numbers, ie host02-region and host04-region.

Would anyone be able to show me how to do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a basic math question. I would change `count.index+2` to `(count.index + 1) * 2`.

```
(0 + 1) * 2 = 2
(1 + 1) * 2 = 4
(2 + 1) * 2 = 6
(3 + 1) * 2 = 8
```

Comment: Thank you i'd really over complicated that in my head

Answer (score 0):

Because I arrived here looking for it, for completeness;

Similarly to Mark B's answer, to get only the **odd** equivalents the equation would be `(count.index * 2) + 1`.

```
(0 * 2) + 1 = 1
(1 * 2) + 1 = 3
(2 * 2) + 1 = 5
(3 * 2) + 1 = 7
```